# how to make array of class objects using dynamic allocation in c#?

Tags: c#, dynamic, allocation

i made a class named x;
so i want to make array of it using dynamic allocation

```
x [] myobjects = new x();
```

but it gives me that error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ObjAssig4.x' to 'ObjAssig4.x[]'

i know it's dump question but i am a beginner

thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
x[] myobjects = new x[10];
```

For an array you don't create a new one with parens 'new x()'
An array is not dynamic though.
You could use Array.Resize to alter it's size, but you're probably after a List

```
List<x> myobjects = new List<x>();
myobjects.add(new x());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use an array but a [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

```
List<SomeObject> myObjects = new List<SomeObject>();
```

FYI you were [declaring the array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(VS.71).aspx) wrong too.

It should be

x[] myobjects = new x[5];

Answer (score 1):

```
x [] myobjects = new x[numberOfElements];
```

Creates an array of `numberOfElements` references to objects of type `x`. Initially those references are null. You have to create the objects `x` independently and store references to them  in Your array.

You can create an array and some objects whose references will end up in the array, using an initialisation list like:

```
x [] myobjects = new x[3] {new x(), new x(), new x()};
```

Answer (score 1):

i Found that i can do this

```
x [] myobjects = new x[]{
   new myobjects{//prop. goes here},
   new myobjects{//prop. goes here}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'ObjAssig4.x' to 'ObjAssig4.x[]'

is telling you that you are trying to declare a new x and assign it to your array. Instead, you need to declare a new array (which will also need a size):

```
x[] myobjects = new x[100];
```